# using jQuery .load and content will not load correctly

Tags: jquery

On my website, I'm looking to have a list of links in the sidebar (leftcol), and clicking on one of those links will load new content into the "content" section (rightcol) from another HTML file on the server. I don't want to have twenty different pages with almost the exactly same content copied over and over. I have shown my code below and please note I have a file called "AboutUsInfo.html" on the server that has  and have used the full path to that HTML file in .load. This is the first thing I'm doing anything in jQuery, so please let me know what I'm missing!

```
<div id="leftcol">
        <h1>
            About Us
        </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#omicronchapterlink').click(function(){
    $('#rightcol').load('Z:\\NewSite\PagesContent\AboutUsInfo.html #OmicronChapter');
            });
</script>
    <a href="#" id="omicronchapterlink">About Us</a>
        </div>

    <div id="rightcol"></div>
```

Comment: You should specify the path to your `AboutUsInfo.html` page using an appropriate URL for your server, not its literal filesystem path.  When a browser executes that it interprets it as a path in the user's _local_ filesystem, which is not what you want.

Comment: @aroth - good catch. In fact, the best kind of URL to use here would be a simple relative URL like `'AboutUsInfo.html #OmicronChapter'`. That way the same URL can be used in development and production.

Comment: @aroth I actually tried 'AboutUsInfo.html #omicronchapter' before in the original code and that didn't work unfortunately that's why I tried the entire link. Sorry I forgot to change it before I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

The script registering the click event for 'omicronchapterlink' is not waiting until the element is ready in the DOM. User jQuery's `$(document).ready` for this.

```
<div id="leftcol">
    <h1>
        About Us
    </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#omicronchapterlink').click(function(){
        $('#rightcol').load('Z:\\NewSite\PagesContent\AboutUsInfo.html #OmicronChapter');
    });
  });
</script>
<a href="#" id="omicronchapterlink">About Us</a>
    </div>

<div id="rightcol"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your jQuery inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` so it will wait for the DOM to be ready.
2. Use `relative` path instead of `absolute` path.
3. You said `I have a list of links in the sidebar (leftcol) and clicking on one of those links will load new content`. Be sure that you are not using same id like `omicronchapterlink` for every links in left column. `ID` needs to be unique so use `class` instead.

So your script should be something like:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.omicronchapterlink').click(function(){ //changed to class just to be sure
        $('#rightcol').load('your/relative/path/to/AboutUsInfo.html #OmicronChapter');
    });
  });
```

Also make sure that you added `jQuery` script properly.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately using the $(document).ready(function(){}) and it didn't work either. I added my jQuery script like this in my <head>. Does this look correct?  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery From Google CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="[relative path to]/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showStaticPages(url) {
    $('#rightcol').load(url);
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftcol">
    <h1>
        About Us
    </h1>
    <a href="#" id="omicronchapterlink" onClick="showStaticPages("[relative path to]/AboutUsInfo.html #OmicronChapter")">About Us</a>
</div>

<div id="rightcol"></div>
```